# KineticJS dragBoundFunc and transition

Tags: kineticjs, transition, drag

If using a dragBoundFunc, how (if at all) is it possible to use a transition to the new point?

Let's say I've got a rect with a dragBoundFunc like this:

```
rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        id: 'yellow',
        name: 'rect',
        fill: 'yellow',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true,
        dragBoundFunc : function(pos) {
        return {
            y : Math.round(pos.y/60)*60,
            x : this.getX(),
        }
    }
    });
```

How can I have a smooth transition when dragging this rect?

**edit:** I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V2AK8/) with what I've done so far. As you can see, if you drag a rect onto another they perform a smooth transition giving feedback to the user about what's happening. What I want is this feedback of a smooth transition also when dragging the rect, that means that the move itself is a transition instead of an abrupt jump to the new position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very nice jsfiddle so far, well structured as well. So what you want to do is move the drag bound function logic to the dragend event you have:

```
dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
    return {
        y: Math.round(pos.y / 60) * 60, //<---- move the grid logic to a transition event to be fired on dragend
        x: this.getX(),
    }
}
```

you defined the grid movement vertically as constrained to every sixty pixels. You should have the dragBoundFunc allow the movement as vertical only and then, have the rectangle transition to the grid on dragend.

Comment: Thank you! Though it is not what I originally wanted, it still does the job. I've put the outcome of this approach on a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qur6F/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is dragging an object slowly, but I wonder how that would be useful.

Dragging and Transition uses a different concept.

Dragging is synchronous, which you want it happen right away with your intervention.

Transition is asynchronous, which you want it happen not right away, but the system make it happen for you after/for a period of time. For example if you set transition for one second, it will happen for one second of time without your intervention. You can think of anything automatic is asynchronous.

If you want to drag with some animation effect, I would recommend not to use drag function, but to use several combination of mouse events; mouseclick, mousemove, and mouseup.

I still have doubt of its usefulness though. If you are just curious, you try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've clarified myself in the original post.